# VSCode <error reading variable> when viewing array elements during debugging

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am debugging the following code in VSCode:

```
int main() {
    char arr1[] = {'t', 'e', 's', 't', '\0'};
    char arr2[] = "test";
    int arr3[] = {1, 2, 3};
    double arr4[] = {1.1, 2.2, 3.3};
}
```

The elements of the first two arrays show as:

```
116 '<error reading variable>
101 '<error reading variable>
115 '<error reading variable>
116 '<error reading variable>
0 '<error reading variable>
```

Whereas the elements of the last two arrays show the actual values of the numbers.

The contents of the `launch.json` file are:

```
{

    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++.exe - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

**What can I do so that the first two arrays show the characters in the array?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following [solution](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/6790#issuecomment-798996995) resolved the issue:

> I found a workaround in this chinese blog
> https://blog.csdn.net/m0_46304383/article/details/113487503
> (translated with google transator). It seems a Windows 10 UTF-8
> problem. I hope it can also help you @georgetian3.
>
> The workaround is: "Windows Settings" -> "Time and Language" ->
> "Region" -> "Other Date -> Time and Regional Settings" -> "Change Date
> -> Time or Number Format" -> "Manage" -> "Change System Regional Settings" -> Uncheck "Beta version: Use Unicode UTF-8 to provide
> global language support" -> restart the computer

Comment: Thank you @George Tian, got the same issue, found only way to fix unchecking "Beta version: Use Unicode UTF-8 to provide global language support"